# Loop infinito em análise de crescimento de altura

Tags: c, c++

Gustavo tem 1,40 metros e cresce G centímetros por ano, enquanto Juliano tem 1,10 e cresce J centímetros por ano.

Meu programa está dando um *loop* infinito quando eu executo.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{

float g,j,gus=1.40,jul=1.10;
int cont=0;

scanf("%lf %lf",&g, &j);

while(jul<=gus)
{
    jul=jul+j;
    printf("%lf\n",jul);

    gus=gus+g;
    printf("%lf\n",gus);

    cont++;

}
printf("%d",cont);


}
```

Comment: Olá flávio, provavelmente o jul não está atingindo o valor do gus;

Comment: E o que deveria fazer? Depende do dado entrado, se `j` for menor ou igual a `g` este é o comportamento correto. Deveria ter um ponto de parada de teste para ser algo que tem alguma lógica. Talvez o exercício tenha sido mal definido, mas não sabemos como ele é.

Comment: o certo seria se eu colocasse como entrada 8 e 17, o cont deveria sair 4, sendo q o jul ultrapassou o gus, mas fica no loop, oq pode ser?

Comment: Parece haver um problema de grandeza de medidas aí, precisa decidir se vai trabalhar com metros centímetros ou vai converter entre eles. Qual é o correto?

Comment: Mude para `while(jul<=gus && cont < 20)` e diga o que aparece na saída.

Comment: eu consegui arrumar agora, inves de por %lf, eu coloque %f e dividir g e j por 100 antes de somar, agora ta batendo. vlw galera

Comment: Isso? https://ideone.com/GsqXRf

Comment: Isso, agora saiu do loop e ta batendo o resultado, vlws

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declarou como `float` use a formatação do `scanf()` como `%f`.

Tem que testar pra ver se Gustavo cresce menor ou igual ao Juliano, caso contrário sempre será infinito mesmo, é matemático.

E precisa normalizar. Está trabalhando originalmente com metros, e pede para digitar centímetros, então precisa dividir por 100.

O mais certos seria fazer outras validações, mas para exercício isto está bom.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    float g, j, gus = 1.40, jul = 1.10;
    int cont = 0;
    scanf("%f %f", &g, &j);
    if (g <= j) {
        printf("Nunca alcancará");
        return 0;
    }
    g /= 100;
    j /= 100;
    while (jul <= gus) {
        jul += j;
        printf("%lf\n", jul);
        gus += g;
        printf("%lf\n", gus);
        cont++;
    }
    printf("%d", cont);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/GsqXRf). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/bmuklhzv-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Math/Height.c).